# Invalid GCM API key. in PushBots

Tags: android, push-notification

I am learning the PushBots in the video. But what makes me frustrating is that when I was trying to create a new project, I input the API key just get from the google developer, it always says "Invalid GCM API key."

Any others encountered this case?

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faop6vBBe3E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are logged in and created the api key in the gmail that you are logged in. (Sorry for bad English).